# flask only loading one webpage of the website and other webpages are getting NOTFOUND error

Tags: python, html, flask

[Flask code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftSux.png)

[the other webpage which is not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43SPL.png)

[the webpage opened with FLASK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPGI1.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot help you without the relevant code.

Comment: Aditya Negi Add the Whole Source code please

Comment: help!!!
have to present this project day after tommorrow..

Answer (score 0):

You should add the whole code into the answer and not as screenshot,  you make it difficult to understand what the problem is.

As I can see, the error display is because the URL typed is:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/about.html
```

But you don't have any route to 'about'.

As I can see in the code you have currently 2 routes, one that brings to

```
127.0.0.1:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5000/book
```